# How to share a very specific application?

Tags: android

I’m currently working on an android application.
I’m developing this application for a small company of cleaning, they need the application to coordinates in a better way the work. 
I was wondering which one is the best way to let the final user install the application, **like for example:**

> -Publish it on the play store
>
> -Send to each user the .apk

Also, keep in mind that the app will be updated in the future so must be easy to apply the updates. 
In the end, I’d like to know which kind of approach can suit my situation and which one is the best way to proceed, thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want easy updates, play store is definitely the way to go. BUT. Everybody would be able to download your app so you have to create an authentification system.

If you want to publish your app just for the final users, they can install a .apk. However, updates will be complicated as every user would need to reinstall the .apk for each update.

That's up to you.